# Connection Error with Eclipselink JPA 3.0 and standalone database

Tags: jpa, database-connection, eclipselink, persistence.xml

I've been asked to migrate the database connection jars for a large standalone Swing application from the Eclipselink JPA 2.0 to the Eclipselink JPA 3.0 implementation.

One big difference I see:  Eclipselink 3.0 uses Jakarta.
All I am trying to do at this point is get a connection to the database, but I have been so far unsuccessful and I don't know why.
Here is my test class:

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] argv )
    {
        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "FlexDB" );
        EntityManager entityManager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
    
        entityManager.close();
        emfactory.close();
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
     }
}
```

When I run this I get this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] 
(Eclipse Persistence Services - 3.0.0.v202012081010):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null].  
Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or 
sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with 
your  database platform
```

The exception tells me there is something wrong with my persistence.xml or with the jar files I am using, but I have been unable to determine what.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="FlexDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" 
              value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here are my dependencies (from my pom.xml maven file):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I ran through the connection code in my debugger and it looks like persistence.xml is being found and parsed correctly.
The call to create the entity manager factory returns.
The exception occurs when I try to get an EntityManager.  Looks like when the EclipseLink tries to create a session.
I also tried using a Derby driver to do the same thing, but with the same results.

Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  It was the persistence.xml file.
I fixed this by changing every instance of 'javax' in the persistence.xml to 'jakarta'.
The persistence.xml then became this.
The change must have been mentioned somewhere in the documentation on the eclipselink site, but I did not see it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
                         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="FlexDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
                <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
                <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
                <properties>
                        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
                        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:"/>
                        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sa"/>
                        <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
                        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.H2Platform"/>
                </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```